# How to get user location with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying this in the graph explorer with my account: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

I added to the token all the possibly related permissions.
It shows me many info but any location. On my Facebook profile I don't have a hometown but I have the current location, and my friends can see it too. It says I live in ***. I couldn't find any privacy settings where I could have set not to show it to any app.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you give Graph API Explorer `user_location` permission?

Answer (score 2):

It was a bit tricky, till I found that *hometown* and *location* are stored as single-dimensional array in response data. Try the code below:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
console.log(response.hometown.name);
console.log(response.location.name);
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

User location seems to be missing in the https://graph.facebook.com/me since a while. Not sure is there anyway around it to get the location. So, I hope that clears up. FB is weird.

Comment: Facebook does not give that kind of info via API any more.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on the permission and you can check location with this.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Flocation
```